# "this" keyword application on nested functions

Tags: javascript, nested, this, anonymous-function

I have this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drag-Drop tests</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var body = document.body;
            
            var cursor = document.createElement("div");
            cursor.innerText = "Contenus des fichiers :\n";
            
            cursor.ondragover = e => e.preventDefault();
            cursor.ondrop = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                
                if (e.dataTransfer.items) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
                        if (e.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === "file") {
                            var file = e.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
                            
                            file.cursor = document.createElement("p");
                            body.appendChild(file.cursor);
                            
                            file.cursor.innerText = file.name + " contient :";
                            
                            file.text().then(function(value) {
                                file.cursor.innerText += " " + value;
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    for(var i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
                        var file = e.dataTransfer.files[i];
                            
                        file.cursor = document.createElement("p");
                        body.appendChild(file.cursor);
                        
                        file.cursor.innerText = file.name + " contient :";
                        
                        file.text().then(function(value) {
                            file.cursor.innerText += " " + value;
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
            
            body.appendChild(cursor);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As is, if I drop two files on the div element, I get this output :

```
Contenus des fichiers :

File1.txt contient :

File2.txt contient : Content of file 1 Content of file 2
```

In file.text().then function, "file" refers to the last file reference declared.

If I replace
file.cursor.innerText += by
this.cursor.innerText +=
I get this output :

```
Contenus des fichiers :
Content of file 1 Content of file 2

File1.txt contient :

File2.txt contient :
```

In file.text().then function, "this" refers to the first caller, that is, the div itself.

Is there any way to get this :

```
Contenus des fichiers :

File1.txt contient : Content of file 1

File2.txt contient : Content of file 2
```

Keeping anonymous nested functions as param for callers.

I know that then does not occurs at the time I define it's callback.
I would like to know if I can attach some data
to an object and retrieve it on a callback execution.

Thx by advance.

Comment: Your title mentions "this" keyword. Maybe I've not had enough coffee yet, but I don't see you using `this` anywhere in the code. Instead, I see you using `file`, which is definitely not `this`.

Comment: The initial code was using "this", but look, I mention the file.cursor.innerText += by this.cursor.innerText += replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In file.text().then function, "file" refers to the last file reference declared.

You come from a C background. In JS `var`s are function scoped and get [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). Better use the newer keywords `let` and `const` for block scoped variables.

[What's the difference between using “let” and “var”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

> In file.text().then function, "this" refers to the first caller, that is, the div itself.

`this` in JS is notorious; especially for people already having expectations on how it should behave. In JS `this` is context-sensitive and depends on **how** you call a function/method.

[How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Sidenote: I see you wrote some code twice, take a look at [Iterators and Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). I use them to "normalize" whatever is available in `dataTransfer` into a sequence of `File`s.

```js
var body = document.body;

var cursor = document.createElement("div");
cursor.innerText = "Contenus des fichiers :\n";

// https://mdn.io/Generator
function* getFiles(dataTransfer) {
  if (dataTransfer.items) {
    // https://mdn.io/for...of
    for (let item of dataTransfer.items) {
      if (item.kind === "file") {
        // https://mdn.io/yield
        yield item.getAsFile();
      }
    }
  } else {
    // https://mdn.io/yield*
    yield* dataTransfer.files;
  }
}

cursor.ondragover = e => e.preventDefault();
cursor.ondrop = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  for (const file of getFiles(e.dataTransfer)) {
    const fileCursor = document.createElement("p");
    fileCursor.innerText = file.name + " contient :";

    body.appendChild(fileCursor);

    file.text().then(text => fileCursor.append(text));
  }
};

body.appendChild(cursor);
```

**Edit:**

> I don't even seen any let, const, function*, yeld and yeld*.

In 2020/21 that's basically a fail on the side of the course. `const` and `let` have been introduced with `ES2015` *(Javascript version)* and are implemented in basically every browser for years.

> How would you name such a subtility that consists of adding an asterisk after "fonction" or "yeld" keyword?

The general topic is [Iterators and Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). I've added some specific URLs in the code snippet above to the different keywords.

Comment: "You come from a C background" <= exactly exact!!!
I just finished 20 hours course and reading your answer I feel like I didn't learned anything on this language.
I found the subtilities you told about very interesting and their understanding mandatory.

Comment: I don't even seen any let, const, function*, yeld and yeld*.
How would you name such a subtility that consists of adding an asterisk after "fonction" or "yeld" keyword?

Comment: @LewisAnesa I've updated the answer. Hoisting and the peculiarities of `this` are some of the most common problems people have coming from other languages.

Comment: Course date is 2016 so yes, there are serious deficiencies in the course.
As always, knowing the subtleties of a language makes the differances.
Thanks for all and see you soon.

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` is asynchronous. All the `.then()` occur after the whole `for` loop has ended. Very classic asynchronous-operation-in-a-loop problem. You just need to `await` instead of using the (old school) `.then()` syntax.

```
cursor.ondrop = async function(e) {
     // ...
     for(...) {
         const value = await file.text();
         file.cursor.innerText += " " + value;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7q9Lphjf/1/

You are getting this result because `+= " " + value` happens after the promise is executed. In other words, in your example code the following steps happen:

1. Add "File 1 contient" to the div.
2. Start reading file 1
3. Add "File2 contient" to the div.
4. Start reading file 2

[...] a few moments later

5. file1 reading is complete, so the promise is resolved and the contents of file1 are appended to the div
6. file2 reading is complete, so the promise is resolved and the contents of file2 are appended to the div

In this particular case it also has to do with the scope of the `file` variable which is changed in the for loop, so by the time promise1 is resolved, `file` already references the second paragraph, so `file.cursor.innerText` refers to the second paragraph's contents.

Instead of :

```
file.cursor = document.createElement("p");
body.appendChild(file.cursor);
file.cursor.innerText = file.name + " contient :";
                            
file.text().then(function(value) {
  file.cursor.innerText += " " + value;
});
```

Use:

```
file.text().then(function(value) {
  file.cursor = document.createElement("p");
  body.appendChild(file.cursor);
  file.cursor.innerText = file.name + " contient :";
  file.cursor.innerText += " " + value;
});
```

This solution will however not guarantee any particular order. Whenever the promise is resolved for a file (file reading is complete), only then the contents of that file be added to the div.

If you absolutely need a specific order in which the contents are appended, there are a number of possible solutions to also achieve that, for example promise chaining.

However I'm not sure if this is a requirement, so I'll not make this answer longer than it already is :)

Comment: Really interesting but then, no need to attach cursor to file anymore.
The idea was to attach a new element on file and references it's member, asynchronously, later.
Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that is also possible if you declare an array of objects outside of all the loops, something like `var cursors = [{}]`
and then do `cursors.push({identifier: some-identifier, cursor: document.createElement("p")});`

A solution based on this idea (using an array) would also offer the advantage of being able to display the files in the same order that you wish.

Comment: You can also use a simple array (no objects, just `cursors.push(document.createElement("p");`

Or you could use an object instead of an array, something like `cursors[file-identifier] = document.createElement("p")`

Comment: and `file-identifier` would be a string that you create based on the file name or something like that.

Comment: Ok but none of these implies to use "this" to refer the caller.
I'm realising, this wold refer to the promise,
so why, when I use this.cursor.innerText it targets the div?

Comment: Because you have declared `var cursor = document.createElement("div");` and you are probably using `this` in a scope where it means the global script. For clarity the div should be declared as `var divElement = document.createElement('div');`

Comment: @LewisAnesa Here is a JSFiddle that may help clarify the scope of this when using promises: https://jsfiddle.net/DariusM/ke2rh51d/31/

Have a look at `f.p();` and what does `this` reference in there. It's the object that contains the `Promise`, which in your case is the window object, the same one that has the `div` element declared.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

Another answer pointed out that "var" scopes the function and not the block.

Replacing "var" by "let" anywhere  makes the keyword "this" in file.text().then callback not point anything beacuse of the execution flow.

Anyway, "let" makes "file" of each for iteration independant.

Therefore I have this code working :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drag-Drop tests</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            let body = document.body;
            
            let cursor = document.createElement("div");
            cursor.innerText = "Contenus des fichiers :\n";
            
            cursor.ondragover = e => e.preventDefault();
            cursor.ondrop = e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                
                let fileLoad = file => {
                    file.cursor = document.createElement("p");
                    body.appendChild(file.cursor);
                    
                    file.cursor.innerText = file.name + " contient :";
                    file.text().then(value => file.cursor.innerText += " " + value);
                }
                
                if(e.dataTransfer.items)
                    for(let item of e.dataTransfer.items)
                        if(item.kind === "file") fileLoad(item.getAsFile());
                else
                    for(let file of e.dataTransfer.files)
                        fileLoad(file);
            };
            
            body.appendChild(cursor);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And at the end, I don't really care of code optimisation (for the amount of line code).

I will generate it with some C code.

Comment: check this: `for(let item of e.dataTransfer.items) if(item.kind === "file") fileLoad(item.getAsFile());`

Comment: Right, done. when use "in" or "of" after "for".

Comment: `for(let enumerableKey in anyObject) ...` vs `for(let item of iterableObject) ...`